# How can I see 'next available' tasks in MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

I'm used to creating project checklists in software such as OmniFocus, which shows me 'next available' tasks: those that are available now, aren't deferred, whose predecessors have been completed, etc.

I've just built a fairly simple schedule in Project, and I want to see the same. From the ~100 activities, which can I do **right now**?

I can't seem to generate such a simple list. I've played around with the Reports but none of them are right. I can filter based on date in the task list view but it feels like Project should do this for me. Can it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you allocate the tasks to resources, or is this simply a raw schedule?

I believe/guess that if you've done the resource allocation (even to "me") then the Resource Calendar view will display tasks in sequence or by date.

However, I don't think Project has got the concept of task Availability, in the same way that OmniFocus does.  Other than by virtue of task predecessors.

Answer (score 0):

Click the View tab, In the Task Views group or Resource Views group, click the view that you want to use. If you do not see the view that you want, on the Task Views group, click Gantt Chart, and then click More Views. On the More Views dialog box, click the view that you want to use in the Views list, and then click Apply